# How to create, package, and install Canvas application in Salesforce Lightning org?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, salesforce-id, canvas, beta-managed-package

I am creating a canvas application in Salesforce Lightning, in which I am using just a link of my website to show that website in canvas to have my website looks like working in Salesforce Lightning.

For this, I have created a connected application and have choose Canvas Checkbox to  make it Canvas application.

**I am sharing my apps screenshots in this:**
[image]

[image]

After that I have created a lightning component and have added this canvas application in that lightning component.
I am also sharing my lightning component code:
[image]

Then I have created a managed (beta) package in my developer org and have added connected App, lightning component bundle, lightning component page, and tab which will open my lightning page and will contain my canvas application.
I am also adding screenshot of that:
[image]

After that, I have uploaded this package and got its link to install it on my other developer org.
Then according to my requirements, it should create a new lightning component and page in new org and should show my website in canvas application inside that lightning component.
It is showing **Installed Package** in my package list. You can see this in screenshot:
[image]

But it is not directly creating a visible tab in current application let say
"Sales". And I am manually adding the tab in current selected application.
And then I am opening that tab and getting the error:
[image]

So now if anyone can help me to get rid of this problem, I will be thankful to him.

Thank you

Comment: I can see that you crossed out your package namespace in the screenshot, and that your canvasApp namespacePrefix is set to myNamePrefix.  I think you need to have your namespacePrefix in the lightning component match the namespace of your package.  Not a 100% sure, but worth a shot.